# Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager. Fragment SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, androidx

Android Studio 3.4.

in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in **app/build.gradle**:

```
def AAVersion = '4.6.0'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'edu.vt.middleware:vt-password:3.1.2'

    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

in fragment

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;


public class AgentsFragmentMapTab extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment mapFrag;


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        try {
            if (mapFrag != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = thisFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mapFrag).commit();
                thisFragmentActivity = null;
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }


}
```

but I get runtime error in this line:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mapFrag).commit();
```

error:

```
( 6664): onDestroyView
( 6664): RootFragment#onDestroyView()
(CATCHED)( 6664): Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager. Fragment SupportMapFragment{270ec77 (5411fd0b-1b45-40d3-b306-1452294a4734) id=0x7f0901d1} is already attached to a FragmentManager.
(CATCHED)( 6664): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager. Fragment SupportMapFragment{270ec77 (5411fd0b-1b45-40d3-b306-1452294a4734) id=0x7f0901d1} is already attached to a FragmentManager.
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.remove(BackStackRecord.java:188)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at com.myproject.AgentsFragmentMapTab.onDestroyView(AgentsFragmentMapTab.java:356)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2852)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:947)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1228)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:434)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2066)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1856)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1811)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1686)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:230)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:513)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at md.qsystems.android.agents.SelectAgentMainFragment.removeViewPager(SelectAgentMainFragment.java:460)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at md.qsystems.android.agents.SelectAgentMainFragment.reloadAgents(SelectAgentMainFragment.java:553)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at md.qsystems.android.agents.SelectAgentMainFragment.access$000(SelectAgentMainFragment.java:54)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at md.qsystems.android.agents.SelectAgentMainFragment$1.onClick(SelectAgentMainFragment.java:114)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
(CATCHED)( 6664):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
gment_)( 6664): reloadAgents_existing_fragments: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once I migrated to AndroidX. In my case the error was related to the way the fragment was retrieved and then manipulated using two different managers. To get the fragment I used `getChildFragmentManager`:

```
this.mSaving = (SavingData)this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_set_edit_saving_progress);
```

While to hide it I used `getFragmentManager`:

```
private void hideProgress(){
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(this.mSaving)
            .commit();
}
```

Using `getChildFragmentManager` in `hideProgress` solved the issue in my case.

Hope this can help